# Why did shevatim accompany binyomin to egypt?

Tags: chumash

In Parashat Miketz , yackov understands that to survive he needs to send binyomin to egypt. So why did many brothers of binyomin accompany binyomin to egypt? Why noy just send binyomin to egypt? By having all brothers in egypt at same time with Binyomin, yosef could have killed all of them and yackov would be devastated. So why would yackov have allowed any brothers to accompany binyomin?

Comment: Who says Yosef would have accepted that? Yosef asked them to bring the young one with them, not to send him alone.

Comment: ... and they needed to carry as much food as possible back with them.